# KeyStorage .Net equivalent for Java?

Tags: java, password-storage

I'm looking for an equivalent to the KeyStorage .Net (http://keystorage.codeplex.com/) library for Java.

The library allows password management on different OS, using the respective native mechanisms to do so. I.e.  DPAPI on Windows, Keychain Services API on Mac OS X, and GNOME-Keyring on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking for the exact same thing in C++.

So far I've found: 
ppasskeeper: https://gitorious.org/ppasskeeper/ppasskeeper
(No action since 2010.)

As well as the password_manager in Chromium (chrome/browser/password_manager)

(Does anyone know of a good C or C++ implementation besides the above?)

For Java, here's a good link:  http://help.sap.com/saphelp_47x200/HELPDATA/EN/70/526bfc1405f94fb519f962ace28feb/content.htm

Comment: So is this an answer, or an "I have this problem too?" question?

Comment: Also, a SAP component probably doesn't integrate with the native APIs as the OP wanted.